# Непонятный текст

Tags: android, unity3d

в апк андроид игры есть текстовый файл.
Скажите пожалуйста, как можно раскодировать текст.

> XXTEAu«EcсЊg¤ўWць\ЦтЛ7sЄмЂЊЗ‡НOEкьП»Чэ. ™ҐMчвГOрvµпЖM}lZ+bџ
>   x“й“ЎУДьт6ЙІЫE№}г‡»gЋoВЧЭ#ioЋlёfоЈ*щйvЅШ›&Qу€tЯ§Џз^юBЬёjJT@MЉВеєЗ КҐGяоёЫ?®°Ь2џ$РM}щpb щ–­;МVќ)іi љиФJu“.ІлЅЃЈ°zYЧtћi)M¶Ї›~ пЃрЏЫ
>   }H{*N‘    Ѕ‹QИM«лJуТ®ЬХяЯЬЏ[уC]ЋЬВ«іEµ[9ЊЩ6 цЦьл7ѓ<•БЭеЮQјѓд
>   ґ:с рЇM‡Ґ—сЂ€Pb7рv›

Это фрагмент
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

ответ: без ключа никак, он зашифрован алгоритмом [XXTEA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXTEA), с высокой долей вероятности ключ вы тоже сможете найти в исследуемой программе тогда и шансы на расшифровку есть [c#](https://github.com/xxtea/xxtea-dotnet)

Comment: Есть в апк файл d11501a1198gh789dc1s8uo0pmkv090c.key

Comment: @WalkthroughLösungen тогда может что-то и получится

Comment: А как это можно сделать?

Comment: @WalkthroughLösungen Выложите файлы куда-нибудь

Comment: вот файлы   https://yadi.sk/d/sKmiOgz1nTvU9Q

Comment: @WalkthroughLösungen https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/xxtea_decrypt/, но ключ не подходит